# How would I apply the easing animation from the keyboardWillShowNotification to SwiftUI's .animation modifier?

Tags: swift, core-animation, swiftui, uiviewanimation

In my SwiftUI layout, when the keyboard becomes visible it moves my textfields and buttons above the keyboard so nothing gets blocked.  This is working fine, but I am not currently able to apply the easing to the animation like I can with the duration.

Here is my view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""

    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TextField("Fill in the restaurant name", text: $name)
              .padding(.all)
            TextField("Fill in the restaurant name", text: $name)
              .padding(.all)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, keyboard.currentHeight)
        .animation(.easeOut(duration: keyboard.duration)) //trying to apply the easing I grabbed from my keyboard ObservableObject here
    }
}
```

Here is my the keyboard responder i am using to animate the views when needed

```
final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    private var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter
    @Published private(set) var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var duration: TimeInterval = 0
    var curve: Int = 0

    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        notificationCenter = center
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

        duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
        curve =  notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! Int //how can I add this to my animation modifier

        print("~~~~> curve \(curve)")

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
        curve =  notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! Int
        currentHeight = 0
    }
}
```

in the keyBoardWillShow notification I can grab the easing, but from there I can't figure out how to apply that to the .animation modifier in the view.  The duration was easy enough to apply.  Maybe I need to make my own animation type?  I am not even sure this is possible yet.

`.animation(.easeOut(duration: keyboard.duration))`

In UIKit there is an options parameter in UIView.animate where you can apply the easing.

````
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve))], animations: {
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)```
````